# R: Hold Values Generated in For Loop

Tags: r, function, vector, for-loop

I apologize for this question in advance, but I've looked pretty hard and haven't been able to find a solution.

How do I values generated by a for loop in a variable?

For example:

```
myfunction <- function(x=1:5) {
                for(i in 1:length(x)) {
                r<-x[i]
                }
                print(r)
              }
```

If I run the above code, I only get the last value for x, in this case 5. I understand that this is because I'm overwriting r each time through the for loop.

I've also tried:

```
myfunction <- function(x=1:5) {
                for(i in 1:length(x)) {
                r[i]<-x[i]
                }
                print(r)
              }
```

But I still just get the last value.

The only solution I've found is to specify the length of the variable that will hold the generated values before using r<-numeric(length):

```
myfunction <- function(x=1:5) {
                r<-numeric(5)
                for(i in 1:length(x)) {
                r[i]<-x[i]
                }
                print(r)
              }
```

But this solution will obviously be insufficient if I don't know the length of the vector to be returned beforehand.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `print` prints the value, it does not save anything, the last solution is the correct solution, you will always know the length if you are using a for loop  eg `r <- numeric(length(x))` - but hopefully your function is more complicated than this, because `x <- r` will do what you want otherwise (no need for loop) also your for loop evaluates to `for i in 5` which is why there is only 1 value!

Comment: My real problem is that I'm looping through a directory and I want to put the correlations of two columns from each file in a vector, but only if they have a certain number of non-missing values. I won't know how many of the files surpass the threshold before running the loop.

Comment: Use `lapply` and run an anonymous function that does the correlation (or returns NA if necessary), no (explicit) looping required!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop only goes through once and it is with i = length(x).  You probably want

```
for(i in seq(length(x))){
    # code here
}

# or

for(i in seq_along(x)){
    # code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize a vector of length 0 and then append your values to it. If you have thousands of files this will be inefficient, only a few hundred this should be fine.

```
myfunction <- function(){
    my_vector <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 0)
    for( i in 1:400){
        x <- read.csv("my_file")    #add code to read csv file.
        #Say the file has two columns of data you want to compute the correlation
        temp_cor <- cor(x[,1], x[,2])
        my_vector <- c(my_vector, temp_cor)
    }
    return(my_vector)
```

}

Chapter 2 of the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) has good information on growing vectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
holder <- c()#generating empty vector
x <- (1:5) #generting somthing to loop

for (i in seq_along(x)){ #loop through x
     holder <- c(holder,i*2)#and put it into holder
  }

print(holder)
```

Comment: What's your question?